# Trouble understanding variable exponent derivatives

Tags: calculus

If $a \in \mathbb{R}$ then we know (by plugging into wolfram) that $ \frac{d} {dx} a^x=\log(a) a^x$. Of course, this is taken from the fact that $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{a^{x+h}-a^x}{h}=a^x \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{a^{h}-1}{h}$. 
So, my question is, does anyone have a proof or way I can understand why the last limit is the same as $\log(a) $?

Comment: $a^h=e^{h\log a}$ and $(e^{\lambda x})'=\lambda e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have the chain rule available?  If so, $a^x=e^{x \log a}$, so $\frac d{dx}a^x=\frac d{dx}e^{x \log a}=(\log a) e^{x \log a}=(\log a)a^x$

Comment: I guess I should state that I do have the tools to derive the equation and understand its derivative, there's just something fundamentally bizarre about the above limit to me. It doesn't seem like, to me, that for different values of a we should have the limit be anything different because it still gets infinitely closer to 1.

Comment: What gets infinitely closer to $1$?  Yes, as $x$ gets small $a^x \to 1$.  If we consider linear equations $y=mx$, as $x$ gets small we have $y \to 0$. We are looking at the ratio $\frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ and taking the limit of that.

Comment: Ahhh I see, that's helping, thank you. I'm still a little shakey with limit and infinity concepts.